# python - missing node error with networkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a few functions I use to calculate some values off of a networkX graph, here's the code for them:

```
def signal_path_counter(G, node, inputs, outputs):
    c = 0
    paths = []
    for input, output in itertools.product(inputs, outputs):
        for path in all_simple_paths(G, input, output):
            if node in path:
                c += 1
    return c

def feedback_loop_counter(G, node):
    neighbors = G.neighbors(node)
    cycles = []
    for neighbor in neighbors:
        path = all_simple_paths(G, neighbor, node)
        if path not in cycles:
            cycles.append(path)
    return len(cycles)

def sigFluxCalc(G, node, inputs, outputs):
    numerator = signal_path_counter(G, node, inputs, outputs) + 
    feedback_loop_counter(G, node)
    denominator = 0
    for n in G.nodes():
        temp = signal_path_counter(G, n, inputs, outputs) + feedback_loop_counter(G, n)
        denominator += temp
    return numerator/denominator
```

This is my input graph:

```
molecules = ["TNF", "RIP1", "FASL", "clAP", "CASP8", "ROS", "MPT", "MOMP", 
"NFkB", "ATP", "CASP3", "Survival", "NonACD", "Apoptosis"]
TNF = [("TNF", "RIP1"), ("TNF", "CASP8")]
FASL = [("FASL", "RIP1"), ("FASL", "CASP8")]
RIP1 = [("RIP1", "NFkB"), ("RIP1", "ROS")]
CASP8 = [("CASP8", "RIP1"), ("CASP8", "MOMP")]
cIAP = [("cIAP", "cIAP"), ("cIAP", "NFkB")]
NFkB = [("NFkB", "cIAP"),("NFkB", "Survival"), ("NFkB", "ROS"), ("NFkB", "CASP8"), ("NFkB", "MOMP"), ("NFkB", "MPT"), ("NFkB", "CASP3")]
ROS = [("ROS", "MPT")]
MPT = [("MPT", "MOMP"), ("MPT", "ATP"), ("MPT", "ROS")]
MOMP = [("MOMP", "cIAP"), ("MOMP", "CASP3")]
ATP = [("ATP", "NonACD"), ("ATP", "CASP3")]
CASP3 = [("CASP3", "Apoptosis"), ("CASP3", "NFkB"), ("CASP3", "CASP8")]
edges = TNF + FASL + RIP1 + CASP8 + cIAP + NFkB + ROS + MPT + MOMP + ATP + CASP3
G.add_nodes_from(molecules)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
sources = ["TNF", "FASL"]
targets = ["Survival", "NonACD", "Apoptosis"]
```

If you can't tell, this is a network that represents a human cell. I'm trying to use the functions on the graph to calculate the "SigFlux" for every node in the network once for every output (so 3 times). This is my code which is supposed to do that:

```
for output in targets:
    print("SigFlux calculations for " + output + " as output:")
    for node in G.nodes():
        if(node != "Survival" or node != "NonACD" or node != "Apoptosis"):
            print(node + ": " + str(sigFluxCalc(G, node, sources, output)))
```

However, I get this error when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\witcher\Desktop\Python Scripts\nx testing.py", line 200, in <module>
    print(node + ": " + str(sigFluxCalc(G, node, sources, output)))
  File "C:\Users\witcher\Desktop\Python Scripts\nx testing.py", line 144, in sigFluxCalc
    numerator = signal_path_counter(G, node, inputs, outputs) + feedback_loop_counter(G, node)
  File "C:\Users\witcher\Desktop\Python Scripts\nx testing.py", line 129, in signal_path_counter
    for path in all_simple_paths(G, input, output):
  File "C:\Users\witcher\Desktop\Python Scripts\nx testing.py", line 69, in all_simple_paths
    raise nx.NetworkXError('target node %s not in graph'%target)
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: target node S not in graph
```

Can't wrap my head around what the issue is. The full script if you want to run it yourself: https://pastebin.com/jBeX7EHs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has this line:

```
for input, output in itertools.product(inputs, outputs)
```

but when this is called, `outputs` is the string `'Survival'`.  So it iterates over all values in '`Survival'`, namely: `'S'`, `'u'`, ...

You can get around this either by editing the function, or by changing the arguments sent to the function.  So replacing `sigFluxCalc(G, node, sources, output)` by `sigFluxCalc(G, node, sources, [output])` would work.

---

As a note, I think this line of your code:

```
if(node != "Survival" or node != "NonACD" or node != "Apoptosis"):
```

would read better as:

```
if node not in targets:
```

Comment: How would I have "Survival" and the rest of the targets represented as a node, some form of cast? The same code on string targets didn't iterate over the string character by character beforehand

Comment: So if you run the code where `outputs` is a list of targets, it will iterate through each.  But if you send it where `outputs` is a single output, which is a string, it will assume you want to iterate through the string.  The way to iterate through a string is character by character.  You can get around it if you ensure that `sigFluxCalc` is sent something that looks like a list of outputs rather than a single output.  One way to do this is simply to send it `[output]`.  (see the edit)

Comment: Seems like that worked, thanks. This is the output I get now: https://pastebin.com/XvL2tThY

Comment: My only worry here is the SigFlux value of 0.0 for cIAP, which should be impossible if you look at the formula, where the numerator is the paths + loops, and the node DEFINITELY has some positive value for those. This bad output is making me think the rest could have incorrect values too. Here's the reference drawing of the network so you can understand why cIAP sigFlux shouldn't be zero: http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article/figure/image?size=large&id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000702.g001

Comment: I think this might be a font issue.  clAP gets zero for me, but cIAP does not.  That is, lower case `L` and upper case `i` look the same in many fonts.  Does this explain your observations?

Comment: I'm almost certain that's it.  You've put `clAP` as a molecule (lower case `L`), but never as an edge, and you didn't use `cIAP` (upper case `i`) as a molecule, but only in the edges.  So networkx created the little L molecule, and then also added the big i node when the edges were created.

Comment: Thought to Ctrl+F for clAP with a lowercase just as I saw your comment, and you were right it was the node named that. Thanks for all your help across everything, you're a lifesaver.